# using route resource form did not post to store function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a form which upon successful validation should show the desired result. But on button press the browser displays The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.

view page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{action('BookController@store')}}">
                <div class="row" style="padding-left: 1%;">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Book Name</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                <input type="text" maxlength="100" minlength="3" required="required" runat="server" id="txtBookName" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" />
                            </div>                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>        
                            </div>            
                        </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```

Route code

```
//web.php
Route::resource('book','BookController');
```

controller code

```
class BookController extends Controller
{   

    public function index()
    {
        //
    }


    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.book');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedInput = $request -> validate([
            'txtBookName' => 'required|string|min:3|max:100'
        ]);

        return $validatedInput;
    }
}
```

Form url 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/book/create

on submit button press, the page is redirected to 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/book and it displays `The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.`

Answer (score 2):

You can either post a CSRF token in your form by calling:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Or exclude your route in app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:

```
protected $except = [
    'your/route'
];
```

Comment: How to implement  `{{ csrf_field() }}`  token? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Implement like this to avoid Expired message.

```
<form  action="{{ action('ContactController@store') }}" method="POST">                    
    @csrf <!-- this is the magic line, works on laravel 8 -->
    <!--input components-->
    <!--input components-->
    <!--input components-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use {{ csrf_field() }}  in your form.

Comment: Please can you elaborate your answer. How should I implement` {{ csrf_field() }} `?

Comment: CSRF stands for Cross-Site Request Forgery.

In this case, Laravel is requiring this field to be sent with the request so that it can verify the request is not a forgery when posted back.

So you have to put only this {{csrf_field()}} between form tag. Like below

<form action="#" method="POST">
     {{csrf_field()}}
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

**Please do this after the form class, because the resource take the @method('PUT')**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{action('BookController@store')}}">
   {{csrf_field()}}
   @method('PUT')

                    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 1%;">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Book Name</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                    <input type="text" maxlength="100" minlength="3" required="required" runat="server" id="txtBookName" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" />
                                </div>                            
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>        
                            </div>            
                        </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```